# Slip ring mounts

Tags: motors, wire

I am trying to research slip rings and their mounting options in order to design a BOM for a project that requires it.

Since I am still in the early design stage, I haven't chosen a type of motor, but I found a couple slip rings that might fit the requirements. However I can't find much information online what should I look regarding how these are mounted or installed. I understand the "through bore" variety are inserted in the shaft and the inner part is fixed to it (probably with bolts or something more sturdy than simple a knurled section?)

I found this spec sheet for some of the used slip rings I found can be easily bought online: [slip ring mounting info](http://www.imajteknik.com.tr/uploads/mercotac-technical-sheet-4.pdf) but is not clear how this fits with typical motor shafts: is this supposed to be attached to the tip of the shaft? so if the shaft is positioned vertically, that means I need an static anchor point above the shaft in order to keep the static part of the ring powered?

What about if the shaft is horizontal? Typically in that case the shaft will not be left floating but will be supported with some type of clamp or bushing, and then the slip ring static part will be fixed to that support structure?

Answer (score 0):

Check out slip rings used on alternators - either radial or axial.

Advantages to both, think about changing brushes etc

One consideration is much power will be transferred through the brushes.

Comment: I've heard mentioned in multiple places online that "slip rings are for AC motors, DC motors would use commutators", that confuses the hell out of me, as I thought commutators in a DC motors is just to power the armature, are they implying to rewire the armature in order to share the motor current with whatever rotary payload you have on?